# Cannot generate solution file of v8 with gyp for visual studio 2013

Tags: v8, gyp

This is really painful.
I followed the instruction from https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building%20with%20Gyp.

```
fetch v8
cd v8
```

And when fetching is finished,

```
set DEPOT_TOOLSPWIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
```

Instruction said to use command "python build\gyp_v8" but obviously, my v8 clone does not have "build\gyv_v8" file. I googled about this, And found gyp_v8 is in that "gypfiles" folder, not in "build" folder. So command I used was

```
python gypfiles\gyp_v8
```

It seemed like working at first. cmd put out the response "Updating projects from gyp files...". No warning or error. But nothing happens!
I think it should generate solution file for my VS. But even after process is finished, no solution file was found.

Am I missing something?
Im almost dying for this. T-T
Please, help me.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting this environment variable before running GYP:

```
set GYP_GENERATORS=msvs
```

Then, after running GYP, do a recursive search for .sln files in your V8 directory :)

Comment: According to documentation, one should use 'ninja' generators for Visual Studio. Why are there two different generators for VS?

Comment: This is not working for me. :p sigh~ Anyway, Thanks for your post.

Comment: Sorry to hear it. I ran into exactly this problem recently, and that variable did the trick for me.

Comment: Works! I used this tip for building the 5.3 release branch of V8 when nothing else worked.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the google is using a new build system instead of gyp. It is called "gn" and i could generate the Visual Studio solution by executing following code in the v8 directory:

```
gn gen --ide=vs out/Default
```

The all.sln is then located in .\v8\out\Default\

Source: http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

Comment: that command result says "gn.py: Could not find gn executable at: ...\v8\buildtools\win\gn.exe". what am i missing?

Comment: Try to execute gclient sync before gn. I tried a lots of stuff before I found this, so it is possible that I downloaded something beforehand.

Have you installed depot tools? (https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up)